# Force reload assigned datasets for Mesh Layer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I am wondering if there is any way / python code to force QGIS 3.12 to reload the data source of mesh layer and its assigned datasets?

Mesh layer is a **.xmdf** file that's similar to **.2dm** with assigned datasets.

My layer:

```python
from qgis.core import QgsProject
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('urib_v61-T_F100_P')[0]
```

I tried:

```python
layer.dataProvider().forceReload()
AttributeError: 'QgsMeshDataProvider' object has no attribute 'forceReload'

layer.dataProvider().Reload()
AttributeError: 'QgsMeshDataProvider' object has no attribute 'Reload'
```

This seems to just force redraw of layer in Map Canvas:

```python
layer.setAutoRefreshInterval(360000)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

This works for raster layers but doesn't seem to refresh assigned datasets:

```python
layer.dataProvider().reloadData()
```

Answer (score 2):

Mesh and all datasets should be possible to reload with

```
layer.dataProvider().reloadData()
```

canvas and all widgets should automatically refresh too.